# How to schedule a lambda function for multiple time in a month

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to schedule my lambda function to run every 3rd, 9th, and 10th of the month. I am thinking of using multiple schedules in the events section but I didn't get any example anywhere.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cron expression will run on the 3rd, 9th, and 10th at 8:00 in the morning: `cron(0 8 3,9,10 * ? *)`

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
cron(0/10 * ? * MON-FRI *)
```

will run every ten minutes on all weekdays. You can find further examples and explanations here:

You can find further examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html

https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-scheduled-lambda-functions-f01931040007